# iOS: handling FBAppCall: how can I verify if a user has posted something?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-sharer

I would like to make sure that the user of my product **has actually shared** what my App requires before granting the in-App reward.

This is the piece of code where I would like to handle the **FBAppCall** callback.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    BOOL wasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];

    if(wasHandled){
    //This is a good place to reward the user.. would be good to be able to access sourceApplication and see if things have actually been posted. But I am not quiet sure how..
    }
    else{
        NSLOG(@"FB App did not handle the post so won't do anything.");
    }

    return wasHandled;
}
```

Any suggestions? Tutorials?